# Q: Redis Clusters and Replication Configuration Parameters

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, replication

With the various deployment options for Redis (standalone, HA, cluster), it is not clear if the REPLICATION section in the redis.conf file applies to a Redis Cluster (cluster-enabled yes).

In general, do any of the configuration settings in the REPLICATION section of redis.conf apply to Redis Clusters?

In particular, does the repl-diskless-sync parameter apply to Redis Clusters?

Comment: Otherwise what is the purpose of redis.conf? by default the settings are disabled and to enable the replication there are few steps ... https://www.trymuffin.in/configure-a-redis-master-slave-replication-in-centos-7-in-simple-steps/

Comment: Sorry, your comment made no sense.  There are several different deployment configurations for Redis: Standalone, HA w/ Sentinels and Redis Cluster.  In general, not all of the configuration parameters in redis.conf apply to each configuration.  In the case of the repl_* parameters, it is not clear if they apply to only the HA w/ Sentinels model or also the Redis Cluster model.  By default, replication is enabled for Redis Clusters - there is no way to disable that.  However, it is not clear if the repl-diskless-sync parameter applies to Redis Cluster replication.